# How get running squid3 with a local datase user?

Tags: authentication, squid

I want get running squid3 and obligate users to authenticate again a local and simple database users-pass file. Can be user-pass file of the system or a simple .txt file, whatever is more easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more comprehensive guide to setting up a Squid 3 server with `htdigest` authentication: http://dabase.com/blog/Minimal_squid3_proxy_configuration/

Answer (score 0):

Using

> /usr/lib/squid3/digest_pw_auth

helper that come with squid installation works.

> /usr/bin/htdigest

can be used to create the user-pass file.